# Why isn't this jQuery working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of `<li>` with `style="display:none"`, I want to show the first `<li>` by calling the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    $('.tweet_list li').first().css('display','list-item');
```

Click here to see the [demo page](http://repository.atwebpages.com/twitter%20test/test_twitter2.html), it currently doesn't display anything since the`style="display:none"` property.

I have also tried:

```
$('.tweet_list li').first().show();
$('.tweet_list li:first').show();
```

None of them work.

Comment: [Bad request](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=CloudPeopleAU&count=5&include_rts=1&callback=jsonp1307598186697)

Comment: You're wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function() { });`, right?

Comment: @Ros yes he was but not correctly.

Comment: your call to the API gives a Bad Request a LOT. You are not handling poor service from twitter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting a breakpoint on that line, you will find that at the time it is executed, your `ul.tweet_list` is empty.

Why? Because `.tweet()`, which populates the `<ul>`, is asynchronous: by the time your `.css()` line executes, the tweets have not loaded yet.

Digging through [`jquery.tweet.js`](http://repository.atwebpages.com/twitter%20test/tweet/jquery.tweet.js), I found this line (line 233):

```
$(widget).trigger("loaded").trigger((tweets.length === 0 ? "empty" : "full"));
```

So it looks like you need to bind to the `loaded` event, and show the first tweet in there:

```
$("#twitter_update_list").bind("loaded", function () {
    $('.tweet_list li').first().css('display','list-item');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.tweet_list li').first().show();
```

Comment: or `$(".tweet_list li:first").show();`. This will add `display: block` to your li element though, so be careful if you're intending on setting it to `display: list-item`

Answer (score 0):

There is no element declared to hold the `tweet_list` class you're referring to. It isn't created/assigned by your code, or static in the HTML. The issue may be that you're referring to an element that does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to wrap everything in the document.ready - and why have 5 when you only show 1?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#twitter_update_list").tweet({
        username: ".....",
        avatar_size: 0,
        count: 1, //display up to 100 tweets, as permitted by the twitter search api
        loading_text: "loading tweets..."
      }).bind("loaded", function () { // code from @Box9
        $('.tweet_list li').first().css('display','list-item');
      });
});
```